# Why can't I add id's with has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm overriding a Post model to **find** tags already created and add their ID.

```
def tags_attributes=(attributes)
    new_attributes = attributes.values.map do |tags_attributes|

      tag = Tag.find_by(name: tags_attributes[:url])
      tags_attributes.merge!(id: tag.id) if tag.try(:id)
      tags_attributes
    end

    super(new_attributes)
  end
```

**But getting a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`**
`(Couldn't find Tag with ID=6 for Post with ID=1):`

There is a paragraph on [this guide](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

> If the hash contains an id key that matches an already associated record, the matching record will be modified. However, the above applies if the parent model is being updated as well. For example, If you wanted to create a member named joe and wanted to update the posts at the same time, that would give an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error.

But this `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is thrown on Create, Read, Update.

Comment: FYI you aren't using the result you are saving in `new_attributes`.

Comment: Updated it to new_attributes. It still does not work. @lurker

Comment: Is `tags_attributes` an attribute of `Post`? How is it defined in `Post`? If it is, it probably isn't a good idea to use the same name inside your block (`tags_attributes`)

Comment: Please try giving more details of model relations , it will be helpful .